# Sending email with CC BCC and sender's address in unix mailx

Tags: email, unix, mailx

I want to send email from HP unix using mailx command.
I have to include cc and bcc in my email and have to use the specific email address as the sender.

But -r (which is to define the sender's email address) will disalbe ~ commands so if i have to define the sender's email address, i cannot use ~c and ~b commands for cc and bcc.

Is there any work around???? cos these are the requirements from the user.

Thanks.

Comment: can't you embed the cc and bcc in the header(ish) text that is transmitted, just like 'subject:', etc? Good luck.

Comment: what i tried to do was to write the cc and bcc into a file along with the email message. then set up the mailx -r.
When the email has been sent, ~c cc@address.com and ~b bcc@address.com are included as the email body, not as cc and bcc. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Just re-order the arguments to `mailx` command. That would give the desired result

```
$ echo "something" | mailx -s "subject" -b bcc_user@some.com -c cc_user@some.com  -r sender@some.com recipient@example.com
```

Answer (score 9):

In my case I have to keep multiple `id`'s in cc which has been done by giving the `email-id`'s comma separated one by one as below:

```
$ echo -e "Hi Team, \n \n Action Needed \n \n Regards, \n XYZ team"| mailx -s "subject" -b bcc_user1@some.com,bcc_user2@some.com -c cc_user1@some.com,cc_user2@some.com -r sender@some.com receiver@xyz.com
```

Also made use of the `echo` command to pass multiple lines to `mailx` utility. Thought it will be helpful.