# How to send mail through BCC in UNIX

Tags: unix, aix

I am trying to send mail through BCC,CC and TO list. CC and TO are working fine but getting error from BCC as `mailx: illegal option -- b`

Here is my syntax

```
(echo "$MSG_BODY";)|mailx -r "abc@abc.com" -s "$MSG_SUB" -b $BCC_LIST -c $CC_LIST $TO_LIST
```

Please help me out.

Comment: [How can I bcc with mailx?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97067/44425), [Sending email with CC BCC and sender's address in unix mailx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10099854/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `sendmail` utility, use can use it to send the mails through BCC:

```
(
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0
From: abc@abc.com
To: $TO_LIST
Cc: $CC_LIST
Bcc: $BCC_LIST
Subject: $MSG_SUB
Content-Type: text/html
"
echo "$MSG_BODY"
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Output is coming like  "No recipient addresses found in header"

Comment: Have you defined the variables: `TO_LIST`,`CC_LIST`,`BCC_LIST` etc in your script?

Comment: `TO_LIST=`db2 -x "query"`  `CC_LIST=`db2 -x "query"`; `BCC_LIST='dipak.das@abc.com' `MSG_SUB="Subject" `MSG_BODY="Body" `(echo "MIME-Version: 1.0
 From: CU@abc.com
 To: $TO_LIST
 Cc: $CC_LIST
 Bcc: $BCC_LIST
 Subject: $MSG_SUB
 Content-Type: text/html"
 echo "$MSG_BODY"
) `| /usr/sbin/sendmail -t

Comment: have you checked if `sendmail` is configured in your unix system?Which OS you are using?

Comment: using `AIX 7.2` and `/usr/sbin/sendmail` permission has been denied could not able to read the file.

Comment: use `which sendmail` command to check if the `sendmail` is correctly configured in your system.  As per the error and above comments, it seems it's not configured, so need to try a different method.

Answer (score 1):

mail (GNU Mailutils) 3.7 has an append option to add headers and values directly without piping them in. Just add the headers you need there, e.g. bcc:

echo "Just testing my sendmail" | mail -s "Sendmail test" test@to.com --append=Bcc:test@bcc.com